# Struggling with a JObject[] Filtering and Matching

Tags: c#, .net, json, modeling

I am working on as specific conversion of Json to C# classes using the JsonClassGenerator project.

This is for some middleware I'm building to hook to a TrackVia API project my company has built a lot in.

I'm building out the data layer now in my .Net app

Essentially I have a Json structure that I need to parse to determine if I should serialize one of the properties within "data" based on it's "canUpdate" value within "structure".

Let's start with the Json structure:

```
{
  "structure": [
    {
      "name": "Updated",
      "type": "datetime",
      "required": false,
      "unique": false,
      "canRead": true,
      "canUpdate": false,
      "canCreate": false
    },
    {
      "name": "Amount",
      "type": "currency",
      "required": false,
      "unique": false,
      "canRead": true,
      "canUpdate": false,
      "canCreate": false
    },
    {
      "name": "Description",
      "type": "paragraph",
      "required": false,
      "unique": false,
      "canRead": true,
      "canUpdate": false,
      "canCreate": false
    },
    {
      "name": "Created",
      "type": "datetime",
      "required": false,
      "unique": false,
      "canRead": true,
      "canUpdate": false,
      "canCreate": false
    },
    {
      "name": "Quantity",
      "type": "number",
      "required": false,
      "unique": false,
      "canRead": true,
      "canUpdate": true,
      "canCreate": true
    },
    {
      "name": "Created By User",
      "type": "user",
      "required": false,
      "unique": false,
      "canRead": true,
      "canUpdate": false,
      "canCreate": false
    },
    {
      "name": "ID",
      "type": "number",
      "required": false,
      "unique": true,
      "canRead": true,
      "canUpdate": false,
      "canCreate": false
    },
    {
      "name": "Last User",
      "type": "user",
      "required": false,
      "unique": false,
      "canRead": true,
      "canUpdate": false,
      "canCreate": false
    },
    {
      "name": "Unit_Tracker",
      "type": "relationship",
      "required": false,
      "unique": false,
      "canRead": true,
      "canUpdate": true,
      "canCreate": true
    },
    {
      "name": "Project_Materials",
      "type": "relationship",
      "required": false,
      "unique": false,
      "canRead": true,
      "canUpdate": true,
      "canCreate": true
    },
    {
      "name": "Record ID",
      "type": "identifier",
      "required": false,
      "unique": false,
      "canRead": true,
      "canUpdate": false,
      "canCreate": false
    }
  ],
  "data": [
    {
      "Updated": "2017-04-20T10:12:00.000-06:00",
      "Project_Materials(id)": 404,
      "Unit_Tracker(id)": 209,
      "Amount": "78.18",
      "Description": "1/2 in",
      "Quantity": "1",
      "Created By User": "By",
      "Unit_Tracker": "R04-5050",
      "Project_Materials": "1001755734",
      "id": 772,
      "Created": "2017-04-20T10:12:00.000-06:00",
      "Last User": "By",
      "Last User(id)": 58443,
      "Created By User(id)": 58443,
      "Record ID": "1/2 in"
    }
  ],
  "totalCount": 763
}
```

Here's what I need to match. I need to match a key in "data" i.e "Updated" with a key value inside "structure" i.e structure -> "name":"Updated" and then determine the value of "canRead", "canUpdate", "canCreate" to set a flag of some sort.

The flag will then tell the Codewriter to add a line "[JsonIgnoreSerialization]" and produce in my outputted text a formatted property like the following:

```
        [JsonIgnoreSerialization]
        [JsonProperty("Updated")]
        public string Updated { get; set; }
```

I haven't even worked with JObjects so my code is null at the moment cause I don't know exactly where to start.

The reason this is a big deal is because I have to convert hundreds of tables within Trackvia to C# classes in my app based on the Json export from their API - this will take me weeks and would like to have a customized conversion tool that builds my C# classes for me - so it would be grand to have.

Not looking for handouts, I'm willing to work for my own success need some direction.

Comment: Did you find the answer useful? Or it did not solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this custom class structure

```
public class Root
{
    public List<Structure> structure;
}

public class Structure
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string required { get; set; }
    public string unique { get; set; }
    public string canRead { get; set; }
    public string canUpdate { get; set; }
    public string canCreate { get; set; }
}
```

And use the following code to access `canUpdate` property.

```
using (var stream = new StreamReader("sample.json"))
{

     var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(stream.ReadToEnd());
     int index = 0;
     foreach (var structures in rootObject.structure)
     {
          Console.WriteLine(structures.canUpdate);
     }
}
```

**Note:** sample.json contains your JSON response.